# Java GUI/graphics

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphic

What are the main 'design' packages for Java? I had a look around and from what I see, Swing seems pretty limited. Of course I may be judgemental, as I am completely new to Java.
With what packages can I actually create beautifull looking GUIs in Java?

Comment: The term you're looking for is 'GUI framework'. Check out these related questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281342/which-java-gui-framework-to-choose-now
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138722/which-gui-library-is-the-best-in-java

Comment: LAF in Swing is not quite up to par with HTML&CSS but it's still pretty solid.

Comment: @JHollanti: Laf is completely customizable

Comment: The question is where the OP thinks Swing might be too limited for what he tries to achieve.

Comment: Absent measurable evaluation criteria, this question is not constructive.

Comment: @stryba: Sure, but it's a lot trickier than customizing a run of the mill web app.

Comment: @JHollanti: no objections there

Answer (score 5):

Swing, and it's not limited at all.

Answer (score 4):

Swing is one of the richest GUI frameworks that exist other than Qt. See it with the latest LAF http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html

Answer (score 2):

Aside from Swing there's SWT, Buoy and Qt Jambi which is the best in my opinion.

Comment: Note: You have to dispose of your widgets yourself using Qt or SWT! They are just bindings to libraries implemented in languages without GC.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/). Efficient, good design, and you may get better looking UI than Swing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot state that Swing is limited if you read this book: http://filthyrichclients.org :-). I think a good choose would be JavaFX as it is supposed to be a "replacement" for Swing in java desktop applications. Other good options you could evaluate are Apache Pivot and griffon (grails-style framework for desktop applications). Griffon can run on different UI toolkits through plugins (Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Pivot, GTK).